# How To Write Non-English (Persian) Characters in PDF Forms using pdftk?

Tags: python, windows, pdf, pdftk

i am trying to write non english characters (persian) on pdf forms using pdftk .

i use this command : `pdftk pdf_file.pdf fill_form fdffile.fdf output output.pdf`

but i get this result in output pdf file :

[image: Picture]

i see blank squares [] [] [] [] instead of persian languages

Comment: I do not know if this can be solved, this appears to be a problem with the pdf text renderer, rather than the code, yet I do not know pdftk at all.

Comment: is there a method that i can write persian characters on pdf forms by using that ?

Comment: Taken from the pyfpdf documentation: "Before you can use UTF-8, you have to install at least one Unicode font in the font directory (or system font folder). Some free font packages are available for download (extract them into the font folder)" so there may not be a font available for the text.

Comment: [help/on-topic].